# How to get a response to the same GSP page

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I have two select drop down boxes and once i select the values and click submit i need to retrieve the values from database and check they are same if they are same then i need to display a message in the same gsp page as "Both the values are same". If they are not equal then i should print the retrieved values in the text area in the same gsp page. All these should be displayed in the same gsp page ony

```
This is my gsp page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="layout" content="main" />
<title>Render Domain</title>

<g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"/>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.testMe').click(function(){
            var URL="${createLink(controller:'jsonComparison',action:'compare')}";
            alert(URL)
            alert(asd.value)
            alert(asd1.value)
            $.ajax({
                url:URL,
                data: {asd:asd.value,asd1:asd1.value},
                success: function(data){
                    //console.log(resp);
                    $("#asd").val(resp.asd);
                    $("#asd").val(resp.asd);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <g:form>
        <g:select name="asd" from="${eventsList}" value="1" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/>
        <g:select name="asd1" from="${eventsList}" value="1" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/>
        <%-- <g:actionSubmit value="Compare" action="compare" /> --%>
        <button class="testMe">Compare</button>
    </g:form>
</body>
</html>

This is my controller method
def compare(){
        println "compare method called"
        def values = params.asd
        def values1 = params.asd1
        println "first value"+ values
        println "second value"+values1
        println "form submitted successfully"
        if(values !=null && values1 !=null){
            render (view:"index")
        }
        else{
            println "values are same"
        }

    }
```

anyone help me out how to do this as i am new to grails and struck on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added small example with minimal changes. I assume it's just a learning task because this architecture is not good for real solutions.

ComareController:

```
class CompareController {

    def index() {
        def eventsList = ['event1', 'event2', 'event3']
        render view: 'index', model: [eventsList: eventsList]
    }

    def ajaxCompare() {
        //You can retrieve entries from DB here like Event.get(params.long('firstEventId'))
        //But it will be better to add EventService to interact with DB
        render status: 200, text: params.firstEvent == params.secondEvent ? "Equal" : "Different: ${params.firstEvent} != ${params.secondEvent}"
    }
}
```

compare/index.gsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Render Domain </title>
        <g:javascript plugin="jquery" library="jquery" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js"/>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#doCompare').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "${createLink(controller:'compare', action:'ajaxCompare')}",
                        data: {firstEvent: $('#firstEvent').val(), secondEvent: $('#secondEvent').val()},
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#result').val(data)
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <g:select name="firstEvent" from="${eventsList}" value="${eventsList.first()}" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/>
        <g:select name="secondEvent" from="${eventsList}" value="${eventsList.last()}" noSelection="['':'-Choose the From Date-']"/>
        <button id="doCompare" onclick="void(0);">Compare</button>
        <br>
        <textarea id="result"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do i need to call a function in  onclick="void(0)

Comment: No, void(0) just do nothing so in that case you can just remove onclick block from this button.

Comment: even after removing when i click the compare button nothing happens

Comment: Did you copy all the code? Button listener added below: $('#doCompare').click(function()...

Comment: whatever you posted above i added

Comment: Could you provide your browser console output? Something wrong with jquery version maybe.

Comment: i changed the version to jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js as this was the earlier one which was working fine

Comment: the print statement in the ajaxCompare() method is not displayed once i click the compare button

Comment: Does the ajax call invoked? Or there is just no ajax requests in browser console?

Comment: i gave an alert and the alert is not coming once i click the compare button

Comment: it is working now.. can we make the text are hidden during the page gets displayed first and based on the value the text area should display

Comment: You can just add style="display: none" to textarea and $('#result').show() to success function block. So if it's working could you accept my answer?

Comment: let me try and see

Comment: the value is displayed in the text area but it disappears after few seconds. How to stop that

Comment: Here are not for extended discussions, please post it as another question